ListModel in Python and QML
I have the below lists in python, I need to plot these lists as x,y,z co-ordinates in Scatter 3d series qml type
USed AbstractTableModel to generate the cordinates using lists
.py file:
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self._data = list(zip(x, y, z))

def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
    return len(self._data)

def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
    return 3

def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
    return None

def roleNames(self):
    roles = super().roleNames()
    roles[Qt.UserRole + 1] = b'x'
    roles[Qt.UserRole + 2] = b'y'
    roles[Qt.UserRole + 3] = b'z'
    return roles

def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role >= Qt.UserRole:
        column = index.column()
        row = index.row()
        if column == 0:
            return self._data[row][0]
        elif column == 1:
            return self._data[row][1]
        elif column == 2:
            return self._data[row][2]
    return None



class ListTab(QWidget):
   init()
   listx = [1,2,3]
    listy = [4,5,6]
    listz = [7,8,9]
    # Create an instance of the model
    model = MyTableModel(listx, listy, listz)
    self.quickwidget = QQuickView()
    self.quickwidget.rootContext().setContextProperty("**myModel**", model)

QML file:
Scatter3D {
id: scatter3Dplot
    Scatter3DSeries {
        id: scatterSeriesPlot
        ItemModelScatterDataProxy {
            itemModel: **myModel*****// This needs to be generated from python using list1,list2,list3***
            // Mapping model roles to scatter series item coordinates.
            xPosRole: "x"
            yPosRole: "y"
            zPosRole: "z"
        }
    }

Here my plotting not happening.
No errros and no plots.

What's your issue? Please provide a [mre].

Tried various ways to transfer the list as a listmodel to qml and plot. but nothing works

Edited the question @DorianTurba

Your file is not valid python syntax. Please, fix those issues.
